# Creating multidimensional array containing database output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Im creating a website, where I make a foreach, that echos out some groups, containing checkboxes, with values and names. At the moment that data comes from a multidimensional array, but writing that array when adding new items, is slow, and not very user-friendly.

At the moment, my foreach looks like this:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'">';

/* NEXT WE CREATE OUR FOREACH LOOPS TO ECHO THE HTML FOR LOOKS AND CHECKBOXES */
$totalID=0;  // this is a counter we use to build our check box names
foreach ($items as $list){
        $totalID++; // add one to the checkbox name counter
        echo "<h2>{$list['title']}</h2>\n";  // and echo out our section header

        foreach ($list['items'] as $cbox){  // now for each item in the list, call it $cbox
                                   // $cbox now holds the item name, and point value
                echo "<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='totals[$totalID][]' value='{$cbox[1]}'> {$cbox[0]}</label>\n";
        }
}

echo "</form>";
```

And my array I write is something like this:

```
$items['computers']['title']='Computer Brand';
$items['computers']['items'][]=array('Apple iMac',1);
$items['computers']['items'][]=array('Apple Macbook',.5);
$items['phones']['title']='Phone Brand';
$items['phones']['items'][]=array('iPhone',1);
$items['phones']['items'][]=array('HTC',1);
```

As said, I can write this, but takes time.
I want to get it into a database, that data above, but I'm having problems about echo'ing it out, I really can't see how I should do.

My current database looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj0wQ.png

Anyone that have some tips how to do this easy, and also do it user friendly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT category, title, brand, point FROM yourtable ORDER BY category, title";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$data = array();
while(list($category, $title, $brand, $point) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   if (!isset($data[$category])) {
       $data[$category] = array();
   }
   if (!isset($data[$category]['title'] && (!empty($title)) {
       $data[$category]['title'] = $title;
   }
   if (!isset($data[$category]['items'])) {
       $data[$category]['items'] = array();
   }
   $data[$category]['itemps'][] = array($brand, $point);
}
```

Your table is just screaming for some normalization, however. It's a horrendous construct.

Comment: Hello Marc, how should I normalize my table? but thank you for the answer! I will test it out.

Comment: For one, split things off into a category/item hierarchy. That way you're not wasting space on all those 'null' category fields.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you dont' want to parse your result into a multi-dimensionnal array like you did before which would be the easiest task but you have to double de CPU work, there is one way i use often in this case:

No1: Make sure your result is sorted by "Category" and then sorted by whatever criteria you want to order your answers as.

No2: Initialize the "$current_category" to NULL

No3: Loop and detect new $categories and output the header as you go. Your script will look like this:

```
$currentcategory = NULL;

$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    //Check for a category change
    if($currentcategory != $row['category']){
        echo '<h2>'.$row['title'].'</h2>'.PHP_EOL;
        $currentcategory = $row['category'];
    }

    //Output the label
    echo '<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="totals'.$row['id'].' value="'.$row['point']'."> '.$row['brand'].'</label>'.PHP_EOL;


}
```